# Visual Studio: Finding a instances of Type used inside loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

This is more of a "How can I do this in Visual Studio/other refactor tool?" rather than a coding question.

The example code below shows an unresolved database object, people, (In this case an IMongoQueryable) being passed to a foreach loop.

```
    var people = database.GetMongoCollection<Person>; // Type is IMongoQueryable<Person>
    
    foreach (person in people) 
    {
        string address = person.Address; // Triggers a DB Query every iteration
        DoSomething(address);
    }
```

In this example, the loop is causing "N" queries to be issued. It would be more efficient to resolve the dataset by calling ToListAsync() before passing to the loop, as only one query would be issued.

I have found several examples where this is happening in our solution and I believe there may be hundreds more. But the codebase is 10 years old, massive, badly architected, badly performing (not my code) and I don't know how to find them.

How can I find all instances of a type (e.g. IMongoQueryable) being used inside a loop?

Comment: Would be easier to suggest something if this wasn't a really bad image instead of actual code, but surely a suitable regex pattern could be arrived at without too much effort?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Thanks, I've changed the question to have some example code rather than a screenshot